# Java inheritance and string interpolation

Tags: java, string, oop, object, inheritance

I'm learning OOP in Java and I'm trying to decide if I can/should use inheritance in this example. Do not pay attention to access modifiers and things like that.

There are two kind of pets:

- dogs (name, breed, age, owner)
- cats (name, breed, color, owner)

`Dog.toString()` should return `"Name: name, Breed: breed, Age: age, Owner: owner"`

`Cat.toString()` should return `"Name: name, Breed: breed, Color: color, Owner: owner"`

*My question is*: should I **implement `toString()`** in an abstract class and override in derived classes? How? I mean, there is only one field. I can't see the gain.

So, I did:

```java
abstract class Pet {

    String name;
    String breed;
    String owner;

    // getters setters

    public String toString() { 

         return ????
    } 

}

class Dog extends Pet {

    int age; 

    public String toString() {

       return String.format("Name: %s, Breed:  %s, Age: %d, Owner: %s", name, breed, age, owner)

    }

}

class Cat extends Pet {

    String color; 

    public String toString() {

        return String.format("Name: %s, Breed:  %s, Color: %s, Owner: %s", name, breed, color, owner)

    }

}
```

Comment: Why does a Dog have an age and not a Cat? Or a Turtle? Or a Rock? Age should be a property of Pet rather than just Dog.

Comment: @NomadMaker it doesn't matter. just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation where you could consider applying the [Template Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern. In this pattern, you define the reusable part of your method in the abstract class, and implement only the variable parts in the subclasses. For example:

```
abstract class Pet {

// ...

    protected abstract String extra(); // Or, return the empty String

    public final String toString() { 
        return String.format("Name: %s, Breed:  %s, %s, Owner: %s", 
            name, breed, extra(), owner);
    } 
}
```

In your subclasses:

```
class Dog extends Pet {

    int age; 

    public String extra() {
        return String.format("Age: %d");
    }
}
```

Comment: A slight variation would be to make `extra()` not abstract and let it return an empty `String`. This avoids overriding `extra()` if it needs not to be overridden at the expense that overriding is not enforced, i.e. the class's author could forget to override `extra()`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't write the toString() in the abstract class. It adds very little in terms of reusing code and makes the statement quite a bit harder to read. Having super.toString() in the middle of the statement would be confusing.

Comment: yes, that was my initial thought. but i was looking something like the accepted answer.